# How to make this JS code DRY? While loop

Tags: javascript, while-loop, sudoku

Here is my JS code. The assignment was to create Sudoku Grid (9). I've done it, but my code obviously isn't DRY. I've tried a lot of methods, but eventually didn't achieve success. Maybe someone can help me to convert this 170 lines of code in something more "professional". Thanks in advance!

```
var canvas;
canvas = openGraphics();

var x;
var y;
var gap;
var count;
x = 20;
y = 20;
gap = 25;
count = 0;

while(count < 9) {
    canvas.setStroke(1);
    canvas.drawRect(x, y, gap, gap);    
    count++;
    x = 20 + gap * count;
    canvas.paint();
}

count=0;
x = 20;
y = 45;

while(count < 9) {
    canvas.setStroke(1);
    canvas.drawRect(x, y, gap, gap);    
    count++;
    x = 20 + gap * count;
    canvas.paint();
}

count=0;
x = 20;
y = 70;

while(count < 9) {
    canvas.setStroke(1);
    canvas.drawRect(x, y, gap, gap);    
    count++;
    x = 20 + gap * count;
    canvas.paint();
}

count=0;
x = 20;
y = 95;

while(count < 9) {
    canvas.setStroke(1);
    canvas.drawRect(x, y, gap, gap);    
    count++;
    x = 20 + gap * count;
    canvas.paint();
}

count=0;
x = 20;
y = 70;

while(count < 9) {
    canvas.setStroke(1);
    canvas.drawRect(x, y, gap, gap);    
    count++;
    x = 20 + gap * count;
    canvas.paint();
}

count=0;
x = 20;
y = 95;

while(count < 9) {
    canvas.setStroke(1);
    canvas.drawRect(x, y, gap, gap);    
    count++;
    x = 20 + gap * count;
    canvas.paint();
}

count=0;
x = 20;
y = 120;

while(count < 9) {
    canvas.setStroke(1);
    canvas.drawRect(x, y, gap, gap);    
    count++;
    x = 20 + gap * count;
    canvas.paint();
}

count=0;
x = 20;
y = 145;

while(count < 9) {
    canvas.setStroke(1);
    canvas.drawRect(x, y, gap, gap);    
    count++;
    x = 20 + gap * count;
    canvas.paint();
}

count=0;
x = 20;
y = 170;

while(count < 9) {
    canvas.setStroke(1);
    canvas.drawRect(x, y, gap, gap);    
    count++;
    x = 20 + gap * count;
    canvas.paint();
}

count=0;
x = 20;
y = 195;

while(count < 9) {
    canvas.setStroke(1);
    canvas.drawRect(x, y, gap, gap);    
    count++;
    x = 20 + gap * count;
    canvas.paint();
}

count=0;
x = 20;
y = 220;

while(count < 9) {
    canvas.setStroke(1);
    canvas.drawRect(x, y, gap, gap);    
    count++;
    x = 20 + gap * count;
    canvas.paint();
}

count=0;
x = 20;
y = 20;
gap = 75;

while(count < 3) {
    canvas.setStroke(3);
    canvas.drawRect(x, y, gap, gap);    
    count++;
    x = 20 + gap * count;
    canvas.paint();
}

count=0;
x = 20;
y = 95;
gap = 75;

while(count < 3) {
    canvas.setStroke(3);
    canvas.drawRect(x, y, gap, gap);    
    count++;
    x = 20 + gap * count;
    canvas.paint();
}

count=0;
x = 20;
y = 170;
gap = 75;

while(count < 3) {
    canvas.setStroke(3);
    canvas.drawRect(x, y, gap, gap);    
    count++;
    x = 20 + gap * count;
    canvas.paint();
}
```

Comment: You might be better off asking this on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: DRY = Don't Repeat Yourself, coding principle for not repeating similar code. Hm, interesting!

Comment: Do you see any patterns of repeating code? Are there any circumstances where you copy-pasted code with maybe some tiny tweaks? Write a function for it. That's DRY in a nutshell. Also, this won't make it more DRY but it will make it more idiomatic. Replace your `while` loops with [`for` loops.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

Answer (score 0):

```
function whileCount9(){
    while(count < 9) {
        canvas.setStroke(1);
        canvas.drawRect(x, y, gap, gap);    
        count++;
        x = 20 + gap * count;
        canvas.paint();
    }
}

//use whileCount9(); anywhere you would normally place the whole while loop.
```

I also noticed you had a 3, so...

```
function whileCountLessThan(num){
    while(count < num) {
        canvas.setStroke(1);
        canvas.drawRect(x, y, gap, gap);    
        count++;
        x = 20 + gap * count;
        canvas.paint();
    }
}
```

us like `whileCountLessThan(3);`

Comment: @smerny I don't see a way to make that any more dry. Yes the variable names are being repeated, but the values are different and unique each time unless there's a pattern to how they're changing that I'm missing.

Comment: just an observation, count always starts at 0 so it would make more sense to just pass in `num` and just do `for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {..`

Answer (score 0):

Shorter and more expressive:

```
var canvas;
canvas = openGraphics();

var boards = [
  { x: 20, y: 20, gap: 25, num: 9 },
  { x: 20, y: 45, gap: 25, num: 9 },
  { x: 20, y: 70, gap: 25, num: 9 },
  { x: 20, y: 95, gap: 25, num: 9 },
  { x: 20, y: 70, gap: 25, num: 9 },
  { x: 20, y: 95, gap: 25, num: 9 },
  { x: 20, y: 120, gap: 25, num: 9 },
  { x: 20, y: 145, gap: 25, num: 9 },
  { x: 20, y: 170, gap: 25, num: 9 },
  { x: 20, y: 195, gap: 25, num: 9 },

  { x: 20, y: 20, gap: 75, num: 3 },
  { x: 20, y: 95, gap: 75, num: 3 },
  { x: 20, y: 170, gap: 75, num: 3 }
]

function boardCreator(obj){
  var count = 0;
  while(count < obj.num) {
    canvas.setStroke(1);
    canvas.drawRect(obj.x, obj.y, obj.gap, obj.gap);    
    count++;
    obj.x = 20 + obj.gap * count;
    canvas.paint();
  }
}

for (i = 0; i < boards.length; i++) {
  boardCreator(boards[i])
}
```

Comment: You know, you really shouldn't just rewrite someones homework for them. It doesn't help them in the long run, especially if you don't explain *why* your code works. Clearly they don't have a super strong grasp on JS basics so they're unlikely to understand exactly how this works and why it's good.

Comment: @MikeC People refer to "patterns" in software because a lot of it is seeing a better way to do things.  If they understand their own code, this shouldn't be much of a leap.  I see you tried socratic method above, but that's not really how a person learns patterns.

Comment: It's a little bit of both. I fully concede that seeing the code does a lot for learning. I've learned a lot just by reading code. But you don't gain that ability to see the big picture until you've learned the basics. Given that they don't even understand how to break their code into functions or that a `for` loop is the right tool for this instead of a `while` I really doubt they'll be able to glean the high level design ideas behind your code without some help. Also, a person can/should learn patterns as a natural extension of intuition. Not just as something to be copied.

Comment: I guess my philosophy is that if they want to learn it, they'll play around with the code.  If not, they'll get some good or bad grade in their class and it won't really matter in the long run.  I think a big barrier to learning code is that you can't really reason it out until you know the toolset, and you don't know the toolset until you see it used properly.  Also my answer above could still be improved pretty significantly :)

Comment: I'd completely agree with that. Gotta be willing to get your hands dirty to get good at programming :)